# Tweepy exists_friendship doesn't exist?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

This isn't all my code but its the problem part.

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
x = api.exists_friendship(user_a, user_b)
print x
```

returns

```
x = api.exists_friendships(user_a, user_b)
AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'exists_friendships'
```

anyone know why? Would really help! Thanks.

Comment: What is the definition of `api`? We need more context in order to be able to help you.

Comment: api = tweepy.API(auth)

Answer (score 5):

You are getting the error because there is no such method in the `api`. You are most likely following and older tutorial, and I think that even the official documentation is not updated yet, even though this was changed more than a year ago...

The Twitter API changed in version 1.1 and added authentication as a requirement. This also caused the change to the relationship lookup endpoint, and thus the Tweepy API changed.

You can find more information about the new Twitter API here: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friendships/lookup

The new function that Tweepy provides for this is: [`lookup_friendships`](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py#L473-L475).

Comment: I was using the official documentation, where did you find the new tweepy function? I'm trying to check if one user is following another.

Comment: The official documentation is seriously outdated. You will need to browse the code from the github repo and try to understand it. Additionally, you can ask a question about this on http://discuss.tweepy.org/

Comment: yes i did! I actually did what I wanted to do a completely different way. Basically I made a list of friends screennames and followers screenames and then just compared them.I looked through the api and there is show_friendship but whenever I tried to use it, got an error. @Lawrence

Comment: @GrantBrown I know this is old, but you should post the code you used and mark it answered. I'm having the same issue, it would have been helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lookup_friendships` method:

```
# Lookup in blocks of 100 users
relationships = api.lookup_friendships(screen_names=users[0:100])
for relationship in relationships:
    if not relationship.is_following:
        print("User is not following", relationship.screen_name)
        api.create_friendship(relationship.screen_name)
```